# Why do you need to derive your custom exception from BaseException?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Every class that you create in Python implicitly derives from `object`. To create a new error class, you must derive it from `BaseException` or one of its child classes (usually, `Exception` is used for this purpose). This custom exception will successfully pass the `isinstance(MyException, object)` test, so it's still an `object`. But I wonder, what's the reason this restraint was implemented? Why do we need to derive from `BaseException` or its descendants instead of doing like this:

```
class MyException:
    pass


raise MyException()
```

Comment: That said: One of the compelling reasons to have a common hierarchy is to allow folks to catch everything _under_ a given point in that hierarchy, or just use things like `isinstance` to determine whether something is in that hierarchy at all, and if so whether it's under a given point. If someone used an object as an exception that wasn't an instance of BaseException, how could other code tell if that object was _intended to be_ an exception or not?

Comment: As discussed in [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918), to be on topic, a question should be about a specific problem you actually face. If you don't face a problem caused by the language encouraging exceptions to be derived from BaseException (and not know how to fix that problem!), this isn't topical here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raise` requires a few special C-level attributes to work correctly (notably these [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Include/cpython/pyerrors.h#L8)).

The only way to get these into your object in pure python is to subclass `BaseException`. Because of this, the python devs simply decided that every raisable object, even if defined in a C module should inherit from `BaseException` to make the checks easy.